# How to order by counts of unique ids of related models

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm developing with Rails 3.1.3 and Ruby 1.9.2 and MySQL 5.1.
I'd like to order model by the counts of unique related model.
Here is my code.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :check_ins
  .
  .
end

class CheckIn < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
   belongs_to :ski_resort, :counter_cache => true

   .
   .
end

class SkiResort < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :check_ins
   .
   .
end
```

And I want to order user model by the count of ski resorts which checked in.

When user 1 checked in 3 times at the same ski resort, the count is one.
<CheckIn user_id: 1, ski_resort_id: 1">
<CheckIn user_id: 1, ski_resort_id: 1">
<CheckIn user_id: 1, ski_resort_id: 1">

When user 2 checked in 4 times for different ski resorts, the count is four.
<CheckIn user_id: 2, ski_resort_id: 1">
<CheckIn user_id: 2, ski_resort_id: 2">
<CheckIn user_id: 2, ski_resort_id: 3">
<CheckIn user_id: 2, ski_resort_id: 4">

I've wrote below, but it order by the count of check ins.

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :checked_in_ski_resorts_count_ranking, lambda{
      {
        :joins => {:check_ins => :ski_resort},
        :group => 'users.id',
        :order => 'COUNT(ski_resorts.id) DESC'
      }    
    }
    # => {1 => 3, 2 => 4}
  end
```

The result which I want is '{2 => 4, 1 => 1}'.
How to add scope for order by this rule to user model?
Regards.

Comment: Before adding a scope first check if you can write a function that runs in the Rails console.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
users = {}
User.all.each do |u|
    users[u] = u.check_ins.uniq.count
end
sorted_users = users.sort_by {|name, check_ins| check_ins}
sorted_users.flatten(1)
(1..sorted_users.count).step(2) do |n|
    sorted_users.delete(n-1)
end
```

Stop writing SQL!

note: might not work :P

Comment: Sorry, this is not useful and you seem to have a misunderstanding.

Comment: Might be. I'm just a beginner. But, I still don't think that you need native SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Since `counter_cache` doesn't support unique counts as far as I know, it will be easiest to store your own count.

Add a `ski_resort_checkin_count` to `users` as an integer field with `default: 0, null: false`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :check_ins
  has_many :ski_resorts, through: :check_ins

  def update_counts!
    update_column :ski_resort_checkin_count, ski_resorts.uniq.count
  end
end

class SkiResort < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :check_ins
  has_many :users, through: :check_ins
end

class CheckIn < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :ski_resort

  after_create  :update_counts!
  after_destroy :update_counts!

  def update_counts!
    user.update_counts!
  end
end
```

Then you can just do `User.order(:ski_resort_checkin_count)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  
Actually your answer is work when total count of checked in ski resorts, but I'd like to add some conditions to pick up specific season, e.g. created at 2011.